# scripting help facebook Age of Champions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

```
/declare my id {100003013}
/declare member1 id {100003013}
/declare member2 id {1525608}
/declare member3 id {1256824}
/declare member4 id {1388786}

    |If my id is not equal to member1 id then goto  crank1
    |
    |if my id is equal to player id then go to crank2 

    /if (${my id.NotEqual[${member1 id}]})
        /goto member1 
    /if (${my Id.equal[${member1 id}])
    /goto member2

 /member1
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=335&sourceu="${member1 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=53&sourceu="${member1 id}"&pag e=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=57&sourceu="${member1 id}"&pag e=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=194&sourceu="${member1 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=196&sourceu="${member1 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%">    </iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=242&sourceu="${member1 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=286&sourceu="${member1 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

 /if (${my id.NotEqual[${member2 id}]})
        /goto member2 
    /if (${my Id.equal[${member1 id}])
    /goto member3

/member2
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=335&sourceu="${member2 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=53&sourceu="${member2 id}"&pag e=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=57&sourceu="${member2 id}"&pag e=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=194&sourceu="${member2 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=196&sourceu="${member2 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=242&sourceu="${member2 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=286&sourceu="${member2 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

 /if (${my id.NotEqual[${member1 id}]})
        /goto member3 
    /if (${my Id.equal[${member1 id}])
    /goto member4

/member3
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=335&sourceu="${member3 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=53&sourceu="${member3 id}"&pag e=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=57&sourceu="${member3 id}"&pag e=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=194&sourceu="${member3 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=196&sourceu="${member3 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=242&sourceu="${member3 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=286&sourceu="${member3 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

 /if (${my id.NotEqual[${member1 id}]})
        /goto member4 
    /if (${my Id.equal[${member1 id}])
    /goto end

/member4
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=335&sourceu="${member4 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=53&sourceu="${member4 id}"&pag e=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=57&sourceu="${member4 id}"&pag e=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=194&sourceu="${member4 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=196&sourceu="${member4 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=242&sourceu="${member4 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.ageofchampions.com/game/gift_accept.php?wid=286&sourceu="${member4 id}"&pa ge=gift_accept.php&source=190&sourced=179&ref=nf" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

/end
```

this is a script to crank a guilds titans in the game age of champions on facebook
the problem is that if you are on the list it will not work
so i am trying to kind a way to make a list with all members 
and have the script determine witch one you are and not add you to the list

i would realy like to have the script find the the playerid on its own so i can attach
it to a web page.
the way i have it each individual has to enter ther id in the my id space.

If i use a log in with facebook app will this work.
I probly have some syntx errors too. but i can work them out

Answer (score 0):

"*i would realy like to have the script find the the playerid on its own so i can attach it to a web page. the way i have it each individual has to enter ther id in the my id space.*"

Pass the playerid in to your page via the query string. Have your script read the query string value, dump it into the my Id variable, then render out their specific HTML based upon the value in that my Id variable.